# TPUEstimator does not work with use_tpu=False

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tpu

I’m trying to run a model using TPUEstimator locally on a CPU first to validate that it works by setting `use_tpu=False` on the estimator initialization. When running train I get this error.

`InternalError: failed to synchronously memcpy host-to-device: host 0x7fcc7e4d4000 to device 0x1deffc002 size 4096: Failed precondition: Unable to enqueue when not opened, queue: [0000:00:04.0 PE0 C0 MC0 TN0 Queue HBM_WRITE]. State is: CLOSED
     [[Node: optimizer/gradients/neural_network/fully_connected_2/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad_G14 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=-7832507818616568453, tensor_name="edge_42_op...iasAddGrad", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0"]()]]`

It looks like it’s still trying to use the TPU, as it says `recv_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0"`. Why is it trying to use the TPU when `use_tpu` is set to False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What optimizer are you using? This type of error can happen if you use a `tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer` and `use_tpu` is set to `False`. The optimizer is trying to shard the work across TPU cores but can’t because you’re running on your CPU.

It’s common practice to have a command line flag that sets whether the TPU is being used. This flag is used to toggle things like `CrossShardOptimizer` and `use_tpu`. For example, in the MNIST reference model:

```
if FLAGS.use_tpu:
  optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(optimizer)
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/ad3526a98e7d5e9e57c029b8857ef7b15c903ca2/official/mnist/mnist_tpu.py#L102